# Using a Fourier transform to evaluate a sinc^2 integral

Tags: special-functions, convolution, fourier-transform

I am working through some questions in preparation for an upcoming exam and I am really struggling with the following question:

Find the Fourier transform of the function: 
$f(x) = \Theta(x+1) - \Theta(x-1)$

and use it to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sin^2(x)/x^2 dx$

The first step appeared to be simple; $f(x)$ is a top hat function $T(x;-1,1)$ and I worked the FT out to be $F(k) = 2sin(k)/k$.

This meant the integral could be written as $0.25\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k)^2 dk$. This is where I became lost; this screams convolution to me but I don't understand how to apply the convolution here to get a solution. I am interested in the method that needs to be used.

I understand that $\hat C(k) = F(k)F(k)$ but again what method must be used to make this solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can also apply parsevals theorem:

$$
I=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\text{sinc}(x)^2dk=\frac{\text{Const}}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(k)^2dk=...
$$

Comment: $...= \frac{\text{Const}}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1dk=\frac{\text{Const}}{\pi}$

Comment: Ah cheers, I didn't think of using that. I clearly don't understand Parsevals theorem enough either as I'm struggling to see where the constant has come from haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the Fourier Transform pair $f(x)\leftrightarrow F(k)$ be given by

$$\begin{align}
F(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ikx}\,dx\\\\
f(x)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(k)e^{-ikx}\,dk
\end{align}$$

Then, we have the transform pair

$$\Theta(x+1)-\Theta(x-1)\leftrightarrow \frac{2\sin(k)}{k}$$

Denote by $P(x)$ the pulse function $P(x)=\Theta(x+1)-\Theta(x-1)$.   Now, let $I(x)$ be given by

$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(k)}{k^2}e^{-ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\color{blue}{\underbrace{ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{2\sin(k)}{k}\right)\left(\frac{2\sin(k)}{k}\right)e^{-ikx}\,dk}_{\text{Inverse Fourier Transform of a Product}}}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\color{blue}{\underbrace{(P*P)(x)}_{\text{Convolution of the Inverse Fourier Transforms}}}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x-x')P(x')\,dx'}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\color{blue}{\int_{-1}^1 P(x-x')\,dx'}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,dx=I(0)=\pi$$

And we are done!

Comment: Thank you so much! After following it through a few times it all makes sense  to me apart from your initial definition for I(x) - where has the exponential come from?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that we are defining $I(x)$ such that $I(0)$ is the integral of interest.